# Use sed to replace everything after match that is between two characters

Tags: bash, sed

I am grepping logs for the word "line1" and need to replace the text following that word that is between the characters : and ,
possible results would be:

```
xxx,\"line1\":\"C/O FRED FLINSTONE, MD\",xxx
xxx,\n       line1: 'C/O FRED FLINSTONE, MD',xxx
xxx,\\\"line1\\\":\\\"C\\\\/O FRED FLINSTONE\\\,MD",xxx
```

I want to replace "C/O FRED FLINSTONE, MD" with "Redacted-Address1" so the end result would look something like:

```
xxx,\"line1\":Redacted-Address1,xxx
xxx,\n line1:Redacted-Address1,xxx
xxx,\\\"line1\\\":Redacted-Address1,xxx
```

I don't necessarily need to use SED but thought that was a good place to start. The xxx represents the reset of the line (not actual xxx) so we cant search by that and I want to leave that untouched.

A more complete example of the data would be:

```
,\"object\":{\"address\":[{\"city\":\"Bedrock\",\"line1\":\"C/O FRED FLINSTONE\, MD\",\"line2\":\"55101 Main St\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"use\":\"H\",\"zip\":69162}],
```

And the desired result would be:

```
,\"object\":{\"address\":[{\"city\":\"Bedrock\",\"line1\":Redacted-Address1,\"line2\":\"55101 Main St\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"use\":\"H\",\"zip\":69162}],
```

Comment: greping ? sounds interesting ;)

Answer (score 1):

Using sed

```
sed -r '/line1/{s/([\]"line1[\]":)[\]"[^"]+",/\1Redacted-Address1,/}'
```

example

```
echo ',\"object\":{\"address\":[{\"city\":\"Bedrock\",\"line1\":\"C/O FRED FLINSTONE\, MD\",\"line2\":\"55101 Main St\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"use\":\"H\",\"zip\":69162}], '|sed -r '/line1/{s/([\]"line1[\]":)[\]"[^"]+",/\1Redacted-Address1,/}'
```

output will be

```
,\"object\":{\"address\":[{\"city\":\"Bedrock\",\"line1\":Redacted-Address1,\"line2\":\"55101 Main St\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"use\":\"H\",\"zip\":69162}],
```

Comment: This one worked except it also stripped out many of the back-slashes which is a problem.  The result I got was:

,"object":{"address":[{"city":"Bedrock","line1":"C/O FRED FLINSTONE\, MD","line2":"55101 Main St","state":"TX","use":"H","zip":69162}],

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want to get everything between the colon following `line1` and the coma that immediately precedes the next colon. The following regex should accomplish that by replacing everything but the capture groups:

```
sed 's/\(line1[^:]*:\)[^:]*\(,[^,:]*:\)/\1 Redacted-Address1\2/'
```

Comment: This is really close but again it's stripping out all of the back-slashes and forward-slashes. Is there a way to get it to leave those alone?

TEST:
echo ",\"object\":{\"address\":[{\"city\":\"Bedrock\",\"line1\":\"C/O FRED FLINSTONE\, MD\",\"line2\":\"55101 Main St\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"use\":\"H\",\"zip\":69162}]," | sed 's/\(line1[^:]*:\)[^:]*\(,[^,:]*:\)/\1 Redacted-Address1\2/'

RESULT:
,"object":{"address":[{"city":"Bedrock","line1": Redacted-Address1,"line2":"55101 Main St","state":"TX","use":"H","zip":69162}],

Comment: What version of sed are you using?

Comment: @user2704404 - The _stripping out of the back-slashes_ is due to your use of the shell to echo the argument to sed. If you let sed read a file, nothing is stripped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this sed with greedy regex `:.*,` which will match from `:` to last `,`:

```
sed 's/:.*,/:Redacted Name,/' file
xxx,\"line1\":Redacted Name,xxx
xxx,\n line1:Redacted Name,xxx
xxx,\\"line1\\":Redacted Name,xxx
```

As per comments below:

```
sed "s/:..*['\"],/:Redacted Name,/" file
xxx,\"line1\":Redacted Name,xxx
xxx,\n line1:Redacted Name,xxx
xxx,\\"line1\\":Redacted Name,xxx
```

Comment: Hopefully there won't be line like `xxx,:\"line1\":\"C/O FRED FLINSTONE, MD\",xxx` :-)

Comment: Unfortunately the logs will contain very large json and/or XML strings that will have hundreds of instances of :*,  
I only want to change the one instance that is after "line1" and not any of the others. I considered using a JSON parser like JQ but one of the reasons I would be checking the logs is for mal-formed json errors so I can't rely on the json being formatted properly.

Comment: First of all, thank you for your help.
That still does not quite work. It changes all instances of :, and I only want to change the one just after the word "line1".  Here is a better representation of one of the log entries that is piped into your SED command:

echo ",\"object\":{\"address\":[{\"city\":\"BEDROCK\",\"line1\":\"C/O FRED FLINSTONE\,MD\",\"line2\":\"55101 Main St\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"use\":\"H\"," | sed "s/:..*['\"],/:Redacted Name,/" 

,"object":Redacted Name,

Comment: The desired result would be: 
",\"object\":{\"address\":[{\"city\":\"BEDROCK\",\"line1\":Redacted-Line1,\"line2\":\"55101 Main St\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"use\":\"H\","

Comment: Okay, my question has been updated. Sorry, I am new to this.  Thanks again for your help.

Comment: That didnt seem to work. It removed most of the back-slashes in the line but thats not what I was after.  Here is the result:

echo ",\"object\":{\"address\":[{\"city\":\"Bedrock\",\"line1\":\"C/O FRED FLINSTONE\, MD\",\"line2\":\"55101 Main St\",\"state\":\"TX\",\"use\":\"H\",\"zip\":69162}]," | sed -r 's/(line1[^:]*:)[^"]*".*"(,.*line2)\\/\1Redacted Name\2/'

,"object":{"address":[{"city":"Bedrock","line1":"C/O FRED FLINSTONE\, MD","line2":"55101 Main St","state":"TX","use":"H","zip":69162}],

Comment: @user2704404 - The removal of the back-slashes is due to your use of the shell to echo the argument to sed. If you let sed read a file, nothing is stripped.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed 's/\(line1[^:]*:\).*,/\1Redacted Name,/' file
```

This uses the pattern `line1` and any characters following which are not a `:` followed by a `:` ; and then greed (all characters to the end of the file then backtracking till a `,` is found). The match is then replaced by the back reference of the pattern upto the first `:` and the required string followed by a `,`.

Comment: This one also stripped out many of the back-slashes and also removed everything after "Redacted Name."  The result I got was:

,"object":{"address":[{"city":"Bedrock","line1":Redacted Name,